# gameobject array different sequence in built from playmode?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

My problem is inside playmode I get expected array sequence: `showing all gameobjects, RedCube, Interior, BlueCube, and then GreenCube`. But, after I built it and test in my android. I get a different array sequence: `showing all gameobjects, GreenCube, BlueCube, RedCube and then Interior`. This screenshot shows the sequence of my array.[image0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoMcb.png).
 There are 4 gameobjects under gameobject - `Levels` [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKtlC.png). Added a script to `Levels`....  [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXQhs.png)complete scene screenshot.

```
public GameObject[] levels;
public Button levelBtn;
int i = 0;

private void Awake()
{
    levels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("levels");

    Button btn = levelBtn.GetComponent<Button>();

}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    levelBtn.onClick.AddListener(onLevelclick);
}

public void onLevelclick()
{
    if (i < levels.Length - 1)
    {
        i++;
    }
    else if (i >= levels.Length - 1)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    Debug.Log(i);

    if (i == 0)
    {
        levels[0].SetActive(true);
        levels[1].SetActive(true);
        levels[2].SetActive(true);
        levels[3].SetActive(true);

    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        levels[0].SetActive(true);
        levels[1].SetActive(false);
        levels[2].SetActive(false);
        levels[3].SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        levels[0].SetActive(true);
        levels[1].SetActive(true);
        levels[2].SetActive(false);
        levels[3].SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (i == 3)
    {
        levels[0].SetActive(true);
        levels[1].SetActive(true);
        levels[2].SetActive(true);
        levels[3].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Inside this script I have a `gameobject array`. When I click the UIbutton, it will loop within the array.length.... But the array sequence is different from playmode and built. I couldn't figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign gameobjects to `levels` in the unity inspector like image0, you don't need to this line.

`levels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("levels");`

Comment: Fixed! Could you explain alittle bit more on why the "FindGameObjectsWithTag" causing this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: when you play game, `levels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("levels");` this line overrides `levels' you already assigned gameobjects in inspector.